# How can I teach my ME System to distinguish between two different identical materials?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have an ME Crafting system set up, and it's quite extensive, I'm proud of it. However it does have its flaws. One is that it cannot seem to distinguish at times between two different materials, that are the same, but from different mods. IE: Steel. I have two different kinds of Steel Ingots, however when it autocrafts my Industrial Steam Engines, it only looks for the Steel Ingot from one of the mods, I have over 200 Ingots from a different mod, and it completly ignores them. Is my only solution to create two different patterns, each using the ingots from a different mod?

I am playing with a hybrid Unhinged/Unleashed pack.

I have every mod in Unhinged installed and these mods as well from Unleashed:

- Adv Power Management
- Adv Solar Panels
- Biblio Craft Mods (all three)
- Binnies Mods
- Computer Craft
- Damage Indicators
- Equivalent Exchange 3
- Extra Utilities
- GraviSuite
- Magic Bees
- Misc Periphreals
- ObsidiPlates
- Plugins for Forestry
- Soul Shards
- ThaumCraft

I also installed:

- Logistics Pipes
- Infernal Mobs
- Adv Machines

Comment: I think I have an anwser for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Forge Lexicon to convert all your steel and put it back into the system you can read about the making of one the [wiki](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Forge_Lexicon).

Comment: I'm going to accept this because it's a great idea that SHOULD have worked, except I'm running mostly Unhinged so I dont have Omnitools. So if you find another way that would be great.

Comment: You might also be able to do this with the Oredictionary-Unificator-mode on the GregTech Electric Autocrafting table, described [here](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=IndustrialCraft-Addons:GregTech-Addon)

Comment: I read feed the beast so I could tell what pack of mods you have sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The ME system is going to do whatever the pattern is that you've given it.  It only looks at the ids, not at the names of the items.  Therefor, you'll need to remove the pattern that you currently have, and add a new one, using the iron that you'd prefer for it to use when you craft.

Comment: If you carefully read my question, you will see that I know this, and I was specifically asking if there is another way to solve the problem.

Comment: @ender i guess I was confused on how you were planning to tell your network which way to make it.